# Has my account been blacklisted?

Tags: discussion, serial-voting, blocklist

I have an account on Stack Overflow. However, now I start to realize that I get constantly downvoted by the "serial upvote reversal" mechanism. So, I created a new account (this one) ***from a different IP, of course...*** to continue on this website.

So the question is, does this "mechanism" have a "black list"? If an account gets this "serial upvote reversal" once, then it's done...any kind of upvotes would look suspicious...is this the way it is?

PS: I read all the questions on Stack Overflow about serial upvote reversal, so please, do not repeat answers for other questions.

Comment: Don't upvote serially and you won't have a problem. Having a second account, however, is a problem.

Comment: @Oded: Someone is upvoting his first account constantly and those get reversed. The question is who is serially upvoting the OP, then.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - There is a strong suspicion in my mind that there is much sock puppetting happening with this account/person/bot.

Comment: *"I read all the questions on the stackoverflow about serial upvote reversal, so please, do not repeat answers for other questions."* - Considering you originally [posted this on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17128135/has-my-account-got-blacklisted), I find it a little hard to believe you read [*everything*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) on the subject.

Comment: Well, guys 1) there is no sock puppeting 2) this is my first time i ever post such a question 3) i did read the other questions 4) my question is whether or not such a blacklist exists, if yes, then i am bound to start over with a new IP. Thanks

Comment: I feel like i am a guy with a bad credit card history :)

Comment: IPs are only banned if *several accounts* from the same IP are destroyed, e.g. a persistent spammer (@Luke).

Comment: Serial upvote trolling is a thing (bizzarly) so its probably a single other user who kept serially upvoting you and the system correctly reversed it. This is irritating, but you dont technically have any less reputation as a result

Answer (score 11):

No, there is no such blacklist. Don't create new accounts.

Being serially voted on is not your problem unless you created a sock puppet specifically to commit vote fraud or if you are part of a voting ring; it is normal that such votes get reversed.

See [What is serial voting and how does it affect me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829).